# Extjs locating individual comboboxes in a Grid

Tags: extjs, combobox

I am fairly new at Extjs and in dire need of help!! I have done some research and tried to look for a solution for 2 days now and have not found a fix to my problem! my problem is the following:

i am trying to create grid that contains 3 columns of comboboxes. The first column will have a combobox that would disable/enable the other comboxes in it's row! When i change a combobox in the first column the combobox in the second and third column all change! I dont wnat that to happen i just want the row to change!!

I hope this made sense?? How do i locate a combobox in a its specific location in a grid and change its configuration?

Thanks guys!!!!!

Here is what i have so far.. this is the format of all my combo boxes:...

```
/***************/
/* COMBO BOXES */
/***************/

//PROTOCOL COMBO BOX!
var protocol_cbox = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    typeAhead: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
   // lazyRender: true ,
    mode: 'local',
    store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
       id: 0,
       fields: [
           'myId',
           'displayText'
       ],
       data: [[1, 'Ethernet'], [2, 'Serial']]
   }),
   valueField: 'myId',
   displayField: 'displayText',
});
```

This is my selection Model......

```
/****************/
/* COLUMN MODEL */
/****************/
var rownum = new Ext.grid.RowNumberer();
var grid_column_model = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
  new Ext.grid.RowNumberer(),
  {header: "Program", dataIndex: "program", align: 'center', width: myGridColumnWidth/2, editor: program_tbox},
  {header: "Protocol", dataIndex: "Protocol", align: 'center', width: myGridColumnWidth/2, editor: protocol_cbox, renderer: Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer(protocol_cbox)},
  {header: "Hostname", dataIndex: "hostName", align: 'center', width: myGridColumnWidth/2, editor: hostname_tbox},
  {header: "Port", dataIndex: "Port_E", align: 'center', width: 100,  editor: port_tbox},
  {header: "Device", dataIndex: "Port_S", align: 'center', width: 100, editor: device_tbox},
  {header: "Baud", dataIndex: "Baud", align: 'center', width: 100, editor: baud_cbox, renderer: Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer(baud_cbox)},
  {header: "Data Bits", dataIndex: "DataBits", align: 'center', width: myGridColumnWidth/2, editor: dataBits_cbox, renderer: Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer(dataBits_cbox)},
  {header: "Parity", dataIndex: "Parity", align: 'center', width: myGridColumnWidth/2, editor: parity_cbox, renderer: Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer(parity_cbox)},
  {header: "Stop Bits", dataIndex: "StopBits", align: 'center', width: myGridColumnWidth/2, editor: stopBits_cbox, renderer: Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer(stopBits_cbox)},
  {header: "Flow Control", dataIndex: "FlowControl", align: 'center', width: 125  , editor: flowControl_cbox, renderer: Ext.util.Format.comboRenderer(flowControl_cbox)}

]);
```

Finally here is my handler function! ........

```
//DISABLE OR ENABLE CBOX HANDLER
function hide_unhide(){
 for(i=0; i<= store.getCount() - 1; i++){
  if(store.getAt(i).data.Protocol== 1){
    baud_cbox.setDisabled(false);
 } else {
    baud_cbox.setDisabled(true);
 }
}
```

}

Comment: This is what i have so far..:

function hide_unhide(){

for(i=0; i<store.getCount() -1; i++;){
  if(store.getAt(i).data.id == 1){
     combo2.setDisabled(true);
     combo3.setDisabled(false);
}else{
     combo2.setDisabled(false);
     combo3.setDisabled(true); 
}

}

}

Comment: Are you using those comboboxes as editors in a grid with RowEditing or CellEditing plugin?

Comment: hey matt .... i am using the comboboxes as editors in my column model.. and im not sure if im using row or cell editing.. how do i find out?

Comment: RowEditing means all editors are shown at once (per row), CellEditing will only show the editor of the cell you selected. Also, which ExtJS version are you using?

Comment: my selection model is "rowSelectionModel" .. soo i assume im using rowediting. i am using version 3.4 of Ext

Comment: You might try throwing your code in the question inside code blocks and getting it working in a JsFiddle so we can see what's going on.  Sounds like maybe you've used references to the same combo box object over and over.

Comment: I just updated my post.. hopefully this would help others help me lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable your combobox, it will be disabled in all cells of that column, because there is just one editor (in this case combobox) per column, which is used for **all** rows.

If you want to disable the combobox for specific rows I suggest you add a listener to the [beforeedit](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel-event-beforeedit) event on your grid which will enable/disable the comboboxes before the editing starts:

```
listeners: {
    beforeedit: function(e) {
        var condition = e.record.data.id == 1; // your condition here
        combo2.setDisabled(condition);
        combo3.setDisabled(!condition);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks matt!..were should i add this listener exactly??.. to my column model or grid panel?

Comment: matt i did this and it seems to work however, if i want to select to change the selection of the controller conbobox i still get the same problem... There is absolutely no way of just locating the individual combo box??

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what exactly you want to do. Could you describe that use case and the expected result more detailed?

Comment: i still dont understand hwo it worked though????... perhaps you can explain this to me .. i seem to be understanding how the grid and column model work... the beforeedit event happens only before the grid is actually eddited.. but after i put in your suggested listener.. it works also when i select a different text feild for the combo box.. its as if its listening to the select event aswell. Anyway its actually workign now!! thank you very much sir!

Comment: The [beforeedit](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel-event-beforeedit) event is fired just before the editing starts (i.e. before the editor is shown). The event that takes places before the record is actually edited (i.e. before the changes are applied to the grid) is called [validateedit](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel-event-validateedit)